# How To Make A Delay Inside Of An If Statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I Want It To Wait 3 Seconds After You Press F But To Do This I'd Need To Put A Delay Into An If statement. So How Can I Do This? The Reason I Want This Is To Play An Animation After You Butter Toast.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Toast : MonoBehaviour
{
    Ray ray;
    RaycastHit raycastHit;
    public Camera cam;
    public GameObject ButterIt;

    void Update()
    {
        ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward * 100);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out raycastHit))
        {
            if (raycastHit.transform.tag == "Death")
            {
                ButterIt.SetActive(true);
                if (Input.GetKeyDown("f"))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Stop Touching My Junk You Pervert! - Tickle Me Bender");
                    IEnumerator DelayPrint()
                    {
                        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.5f);
                        print("Delayed!");
                    }
                    Debug.Log("WEE WOO WEE WOO - Patrick");

                }
            }
            else
            {
                ButterIt.SetActive(false);
            }
        }

    }
}


void Start()
    {
        cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
    StartCoroutine(DelayPrint);
    }
```

Comment: Also if I don't anwser I'm asleep

Comment: I'm not a Unity user, but isn't that what Unity's coroutines enable you to do?

Comment: Well it doesn't let you put in into an if statement that I know that's why I'm posting it

Comment: You mean Unity's `StartCoroutine` method can't be used inside an `if` statement?

Comment: the way I know it you have ti put the delay into a IEnumerator

Comment: But why is that an issue?

Comment: because it fails when I put a inumerator into an if statement

Comment: Perhaps you should show that code so people can help you fix it? It seems like you're doing it incorrectly.

Comment: is the code not loading for you?

Comment: I see the code you've provided. That doesn't include your _"it fails when I put an inumerator [sic] into an if statement"_ code.

Comment: I gotta sleep now sorry

Comment: You can't delay the main thread, which is where your update loop is called, without freezing the entire game. You could start a coroutine that waits and then does something. You would need logic in Update to skip the appropriate actins it does while that coroutine is running.

Comment: Why is `cam` public? What is this doing here `cam = GetComponent<Camera>();`? Do you have multiple cameras? If so, why? Why is `ButterIt` set as active if a rayhit touches Death? What is Death? Why do you call rayhits every frame? Why do you call `ButterIt.SetActive();` (depending on rayhit) almost every frame? What does *After You Butter Toast* mean? Is it an animation? As a small optimization, use `CompareTag()` instead of `transform.tag=="Death"`. A best practice is using `GetKeyUp()` instead of `GetKeyDown()` unless you want something to be called while the key is pressed.

Comment: @TheNomad "A best practice is using GetKeyUp() instead of GetKeyDown() unless you want something to be called while the key is pressed." - this is wrong. `GetKey` does what you describe. `GetKeyDown` and `GetKeyUp` are only true on the rising/falling edge frame of the key press, respectively.

Comment: My bad, I confirm I confused it with `GetKey()` last night. Thanks for catching it. Still the rest of the points stand.

Comment: @TheNomad I made the camera public so I can put it in the inspector. And ButterIt is text that appears when the raycast that hits the toast. Death is a tag and I called it that because I want you to die when you butter the toast. And ik my code is bad and that's because I'm new

Comment: If you assign the camera in the Inspector, why is this line in `Start()` ? `cam = GetComponent<Camera>();` . You assign it in the Inspector so that you don't call `GetComponent()`.  Conversely, if you call GetComponent, you set it as `protected` or `private` and maybe assign a property as getter *if* it's needed externally. A component is not a variable. Meaning, assigning in the Inspector doesn't make it a variable that you need to "get".  I am not "attacking" your code, just trying to understand it and hopefully, make you improve it :) We all started new, so don't worry, just be open minded.

Comment: I know *Death* is a tag,  my underlying question was, what it is applied to. The code is not clear regarding the workflow, also because of the joking `Debug.Log()` calls. You didn't answer if *After You Butter Toast* is an animation.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention butter toast is the hitbox that is for detecting if you're mouse is facing near the butter and the toast so I called it butter toast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 different ways to delay execution of a block of code.

The best way is to use a coroutine. Information about coroutines can be found in the [manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).

Here's a brief example

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour {
   private IEnumerator DelayPrint (float seconds) {
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
      print("Delayed!");
   }

   void Update() {
      if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)) {
         StartCoroutine(DelayPrint(5f));
      }

   }
}
```

Another way is to use a timer variable. The timer starts incrementing once `someCondition` becomes true, and stops once it reached 5 seconds (or however much time you want)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Example2 : MonoBehaviour {
   private float myTimer = 0f;
   private bool isCounting = false;

   // A condition you set during the execution of the program.
   private bool someCondition;

   Update () {

      // Check the condition
      if (someCondition)
         isCounting = true;

      // Increment the timer
      if (isCounting)
         myTimer += Time.deltaTime;

      // If the timer has been going for 5 seconds
      if (myTimer > 5f)
      {
          // Execute DoSomething() once.
          myTimer = 0;
          isCounting = false;
          DoSomething();
      }
   }
}
```

A final option is not recommended, but you can use `Invoke(methodName, seconds)` to invoke a method after `seconds` seconds. You can also use `Invoke(nameof(method), seconds)` to prevent the method from being stripped in the build if it isn't used anywhere else.

Comment: Thank you. I see in the comments you said you had an issue with setting up the coroutine to work properly. I believe my code snippet properly demonstrates how to delay the execution of code. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Mushy Avacado@ top level statements must precede namespace and type declarations is the error i get and I edited the code in the post

Comment: I updated the post. I hadn't included using declarations in the code snippet.

Comment: this is too long so I'm putting a pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/YUieVdrC also I didn't notice your comment when I posted this. @MushyAvocado

Comment: That's because you're only incrementing MyTime the frame when the key F was pressed down. You need to move line 31 to line 43 and wrap it in an if statement `if(isCounting) { }` Also place the check for the timer `if (MyTimer > 3f)` out of the if statement. The only thing for the delay code that should be in the if statement is `isCounting = true`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/SwrWVXHh Ok I tried that and it still fails

Comment: Close - don't set isCounting to false when the key isn't being pressed. Set it after you've printed WEE WOO WEE WOO to the console.

Comment: @Leon Why don't you use the first example with `StartCoroutine()`? It would get the job done, even though I am not a fan of coroutines. `InvokeRepeating()`  is ok, but just cos I am old school; technically speaking, coroutines give you more control.

Comment: @MushyAvocado I recommend to add a `seconds* Time.timeScale` too for `WaitForSeconds()` if you want to be accurate in game time.  Or at least specify it as a comment.

Comment: @TheNomad `WaitForSeconds` is already affected by time scale. `WaitForSecondsRealtime` is the version that is not.

Comment: Thanks so much this thread was so long but finally you helped me fix it!